# RSS feed rewrite matching wrong rule

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, rewrite-rules

I'm attempting to add a rewrite so feeds for pages that list specific post categories work.

eg. `/mining-civil-engineering/newsroom/feed/` would point to `index.php?cat=21,22&feed=rss2`

These rewrites are added programatically based on a template type, so they don't have to be added manually. I'm using `add_rewrite_rule`.

Unfortunately, `$wp_rewrite` still seems to only match to the rule designating page comments `(.?.+?)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$` outputting to `pagename=mining-civil-engineering%2Fnews-events&feed=feed`.

I tried using `$wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules` so my .htaccess now looks like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^national-security/events/feed/ /index.php?cat=10&feed=rss2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^mining-civil-engineering/news-events/feed/ /index.php?cat=21,22&feed=rss2 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Unfortunately it still seems to only match on the previous query. I commented out in my htaccess lines until it knew it was only working with the rewrite I wanted, but the body still returned the comments feed, and my debugging showing it was matching on the feed url. I did flush with both `$wp_rewrite->flush_rules( true );` and re-saving permalinks in the admin.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? I'm utterly lost.

Thanks!!

Comment: Manually rewriting URLs in `.htaccess` (to override WordPress's default behaviour) is often problematic because WordPress still sees the original URL on the request (ie. `/national-security/events/feed/` - the value of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`) and routes the request according to that. (?)

Comment: @MrWhite - so I have to make it work with add_rewrite_rule() but to do that I'd have to remove the rewrite in the list that it's catching on perhaps?

Answer (score -1):

The solution was to modify my regex slightly in my `add_rewrite_rule`.

The rule was `^/mining-civil-engineering/news-events/feed/` and now reads
`^/mining-civil-engineering/news-events/(feed|rss2)/?$`

Comment: What exactly did you have to change? The regex in your example looks like it would match? Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: This answer will not help anyone with the same problem. Please be more specific.